# Read Text File Up to GO

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, filestream, streamreader

I have a multi-megabyte .sql file, there are GO statements on newlines every 10k or so. I am trying to come up with a way to read the file, line-by-line, until I hit a new line that only has "go" and a Newline character, then return what was read to the caller, and then read the next bunch of text until I hit GO again.

Peek only lets me read one character, what's a smart way to make this work in C# on Framework 4.0?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do exactly what you were saying.
Call this function with a string of the filename of the SQL file, and it will return an `IEnumerable<string>` (a bunch of strings) that each hold a SQL batch (each up until a `GO` statement) which you can then loop through with `foreach` or anything else.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> GetSqlBatches(string filename)
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filename))
    {
        StringBuilder ReadSoFar = new StringBuilder();

        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            string line = sr.ReadLine();
            ReadSoFar.AppendLine(line);
            if (line.Trim() == "GO")
            {
                yield return ReadSoFar.ToString();
                ReadSoFar = new StringBuilder();
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use SQL Server there is no need to parse file manually. Use  [Server.ConnectionContext.ExecuteNonQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms199350.aspx) method instead. It is part of SMO.

See [Handling "GO" Separators in SQL Scripts - the easy way](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2006/11/07/Handling-_2200_GO_2200_-Separators-in-SQL-Scripts-_2D00_-the-easy-way.aspx) by Jon Galloway.

Comment: From the requirement "return what was read", it doesn't sound like `ExecuteNonQuery` would be appropriate.  But my SQL experience is limited.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the file with a [BufferedStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.bufferedstream.aspx) then you can seek back to the beginning of the line once you read a "GO" token.

If the file will always be on disk (instead of in memory or coming from a network connection), you can also just use a [FileStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.aspx) because that is also seekable.